# How can I remove the space between header and body in PDF report?

Tags: report, odoo, openerp-8

I've customized my sales report to look from this:

---

[image]

---

To this:

---

[image]

---

I commented the code section that shows the company information inside `external_layout_header` view:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<t t-name="report.external_layout_header">
    <div class="header">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-3">
                <img t-if="company.logo" t-att-src="'data:image/png;base64,%s' % company.logo" style="max-height: 45px;"/>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-9 text-right" style="margin-top:20px;" t-field="company.rml_header1"/>
        </div>
        <div class="row zero_min_height">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <div style="border-bottom: 1px solid black;"/>
            </div>
        </div>
<!-- COMMENTED
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-3">
                <div t-field="company.partner_id" t-field-options="{'widget': 'contact', 'fields': ['address', 'name'], 'no_marker': true}" style="border-bottom: 1px solid black;"/>
            </div>
        </div>
-->
    </div>
</t>
```

Somehow, I was expecting to reduce the space between the header and the report body. I've been trying out different ways with no luck. There's a similar [question](https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/openerp-reports-how-to-reduce-space-between-company-header-and-text-body-63216) in the Odoo forum but that's for v7 with RML (deprecated). I'm using Odoo v8 QWeb report.

### Edit 1:

I already tried @Paulo's solution:

---

[image]

---

But this is not what I'm looking for. I need to gain space by moving the body near the header and not the other way around

### Edit 2 (Solution):

As suggested by @Paulo's comment, playing around with the combination of fields `margin_top` and `header_spacing` did the trick. I reduced `margin_top` from `40` to `20` and `header_spacing` from `35` to `15`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The solution is on the Paper Format: in my case A4.

You have to go to Settings > Technical > Reports > Paper Format > A4
and decrease the Header spacing value

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Although, that moves the header down. I'm actually trying to gain space by moving the body near the header and replace the space left by commenting the company info

Comment: Now, at the sama place, you have to edit Top Margin (mm)

Comment: Yup! That combination works for me! Update your answer so I can accept it as correct

Answer (score 4):

Creating new paper format is the best way for your custom report. If you change default paper format, will have problem for other reports.

Firstly, you need to create **xml** file for your custom paper format and then declare that paper format in your **module_report.xml** file.

You can declare just like that:

```
<record id="new_id" model="ir.actions.report.xml">
    <field name="paperformat_id" ref="module.new_paper_format"/>
</record>
```

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I'm aware that the change will affect other reports. I will consider your suggestion

Comment: Thanks. I created the xml file for new paper format. Can u please describe how to declare that in my report.xml file

Answer (score 0):

I success declare that paper format in my module_report.xml file, please put following sample after your report part:

```
    <record id="YOUR_FORMAT_ID" model="report.paperformat">
    <field name="name">YOUR PAPER FORMAT NAME</field>
    <field name="default" eval="True" />
    <field name="format">A4</field>
    <field name="page_height">0</field>
    <field name="page_width">0</field>
    <field name="orientation">Portrait</field>
    <field name="margin_top">20</field>
    <field name="margin_bottom">23</field>
    <field name="margin_left">7</field>
    <field name="margin_right">7</field>
    <field name="header_line" eval="False" />
    <field name="header_spacing">15</field>
    <field name="dpi">90</field>
    <field name="report_ids" eval="[(4, ref('YOUR_MODULE.REPORT_ID'))]"></field>
</record>
```